# How do I add Allegro (or any library) to the header include path on Mac?

Tags: c++, c, macos, header, allegro

I had no problem with Allegro while using Linux, but I can't figure out how to include the library on OS X. I built it from source originally, but I uninstalled it to try the MacPorts version. The headers are currently in `/opt/local/include/allegro5/`.

I can't use `#include <allegro5/allegro.h>` or

`#include "/opt/local/include/allegro5/allegro.h"`.

Based on the compile errors, I think the Allegro headers reference each other by

`#include <allegro5/other_header.h>`.

So how do I add the allegro5 directory to the include path for gcc/g++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data in this post, it looks like the correct include path is `/opt/local/include`. When gcc/g++ attempts to #include <allegro5/allegro.h>, it will add that relative path to the base include paths in its list in order to eventually form the string `/opt/local/include/allegro5/allegro.h` where it will locate a proper file.

If you're compiling via command line with gcc/g++, add the option `-I/opt/local/include`. If you're using Xcode, well, I'm not so familiar with that, but I'm confident that you would need to dig around in the project's settings and find a UI widget that allows you to add additional include paths.